# Power Query Function - get column name

Tags: powerquery, m

I have different files containing various attributes (one file will have Job Name, another one will have Location, another one will have Grade, etc.).

**Sample Data:**

| Job Name | Job Location | Job Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Controller | Some values | High |
| Director | No Values | Low |
| Analyst | Some Other values |  |
| VP Of Finance | Blank | Medium |
| Director |  |  |

I want to have a function that will add a column in which each cell will have combined: the Column Name (Job Name in case of the above sample) AND length of the Column Name (Length of each Job Name in case of the above sample).

**Desired Output:**

| Job Name | Job Location | Job Grade | Desired Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Controller | Some values | High | Job Name 10 |
| Director | No Values | Low | Job Name 8 |
| Analyst | Some Other values |  | Job Name 7 |
| VP Of Finance | Blank | Medium | Job Name 13 |
| Director |  | Executive | Job Name 8 |

What I have is:

```
(MyColumn) as text =>

let 

Source = Text.Length(MyColumn),
NewSource = Number.ToText(Source),
FinalText = Text.Combine({MyColumn,NewSource}," ")

in FinalText
```

I need to find a way to reference the column name to be added to the FinalText, because for now the output is following:

| Job Name | Current Output (incorrect!) |
| --- | --- |
| Engineer | Engineer 1 |
| Director | Director 2 |
| Analyst | Analyst 3 |
| Engineer | Engineer 1 |

Btw I tried using Record.Field(_, MyColumn) but it didn't work with below error:

```
An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: The name '_' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Edit: I have edited the post, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: ``Table.ColumnNames(table as table) as list``

Comment: How should I embed this in my function, please?

Comment: I am not able to figure out what you are asking for. Please provide sample input and desired output.  Are you trying to merge in a column from another query, where the name of the column to merge in is dynamic ?

Comment: @horseyride I am trying to add create a function that will add a column to the existing table. in this column, each cell should be combined out of two factors. Column Name (Job Name) & Length of the cell. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Not really.  Are you bringing in the column from the same query? From a different query?   What does length of the cell mean.  You want to bring in the value "ABCD" as well as know that it is 4 characters long? Again, provide sample inputs and output

Comment: I have prepared both sample data and desired output in the tables in my initial post. Is it visible? To your question - yes, from the same query. For the value "ABCD", assuming that the header is "Alphabet" I'd like to have the "Alphabet 4". For value DEFG, I'd like to have "Alphabet 5", etc.

Comment: You question is visible but does not provide the information.  You cant have output **Job Name 10** without showing any input that information could have come from.  If you are not willing to edit your question, I hope someone else is able to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247883/discussion-between-marekmarek-and-horseyride).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
zzz = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepNameHere", "Custom", each Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepNameHere"){0} &" "& Text.From(Text.Length(Record.Field(_,Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepNameHere"){0}))))
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I did one more edit to the initial post. What you proposed is not what I am looking for, because it will not always be the first column that I want to reference. 

I am already passing the column name in the MyColumn parameter (see my M code above). Is there a way to reference this parameter value in the Text.Combine function?

Plus I'd like to have this in the function (so the user can click "Invoke Custom Function", select the column from the table (query), and it will be automatically populated), instead of copy & paste the formula. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar answer.

Table1 looks like this.

| Job Name |
| --- |
| Controller |
| Director |
| Analyst |
| VP Of Finance |
| Director |

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Output", each Text.Combine({
           Table.ColumnNames(Source){0}," ",
           Text.From(Text.Length(Record.Field(_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){0})))
           }))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

---

### Edit 1 from comment:

Based on what you want I recommend that you don't use "Add Column>Invoke Custom Function". Instead in the "Applied Steps" right click and choose "Insert step after" you would then type in the `=function_name(prior_step_table,number_of_column)` the function is below.

```
(Table as table, column_n as number) => 
let
    Source = Table,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Output", each Text.Combine({Table.ColumnNames(Source){column_n}," ",Text.From(Text.Length(Record.Field(_,Table.ColumnNames(Source){column_n})))}))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: yes, very similar.

Comment: Thank you for help, Shane S. However, this is not what I exactly need. I have edited the initial post. It will not always be the first column that I am referencing. Plus, I would like to have this in the function (instead of adding the formula manually).
Ideally I would like the parameter value MyColumn to be used in the Text.Combine function (see M code above).

Comment: @MarekMarek I don't know how you are going to do this just using the "Add Column by invoked function".